# Instantiate File object in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, fileapi

I'm trying to create an image file from a blob-object using the [File API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) and then add it to a form to be sent via XHR. Works like a charm in chrome, but crashes the app in Microsoft Edge.

```
let file = new File([blobContent], "image.png");

let form = new FormData();
form.append("file", file);
```

Are there any alternatives to the File API or workarounds to attach a file to the form? If I just add the blob to the form it's not recognized as an image.

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem. I want to create a File with a string content and name. This works fine in every other browser but throws Function expected in EDGE: `filename='a';data='b';new File(new Blob([data]))`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Currently IE11, and Edge support the FileAPI but not the File constructor.

In the link that you posted to `caniuse.com`, there are notes for IE and Edge stating that the File constructor is not supported. I encountered the same issue and my work around was to use `Blob` instead of `File`, and then set the type of the blob.

```
var blob = new Blob([blobContent], {type : 'image/jpeg'});
```

Comment: In addition, if you then set `blob.name = "image.png"`, the browser will treat it in the same way as a `File`

Comment: Good solution, but how would you test if the type of your variable is a file in this case? And I also need to differentiate between blobs and files...

Answer (score 13):

This is what I did and works

```
// to change Blob to File
private blobToFile(theBlob: Blob, fileName: string): File {
   const b: any = theBlob;
   b.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
   b.name = fileName;
   return b as File;
}

let file;
if (!navigator.msSaveBlob) { // detect if not Edge
   file = new File([b], document.originalName, { type: document.mimeType });
} else {
   file = new Blob([b], { type: document.mimeType });
   file = this.blobToFile(file, document.originalName);
}
```

Now can continue by variable file as a File in Edge or other browsers.

Comment: didn't work for me. Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363