# Javascript-Edge browser- TypeError: Function expected

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

This code will show an error: `TypeError: Function expected`

```
function btnUploadImageEvent() {
    $(document).on("click", "#btn-upload-image", function () {

        // Iterate all td's in second column
        $("#table-image tbody tr:not(:first-child)").each(function (index, value) {
            var blob = value.cells[5].innerText;
            var fileName = (index + 1) + ".jpg";

            srcToFile(blob, fileName, "image/jpeg")
                .then(function (file) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("file", file);

                    PassingBlobToServer(formData);
                }, function (error) {
                    MsgBox("Error", error, "error", "#upload-image-modal");
                }).then(function () {
                });
        });
    });
}

function srcToFile(src, fileName, mimeType) {
    return (fetch(src)
        .then(function (res) { return res.arrayBuffer(); })
        .then(function (buf) { return new File([buf], fileName, { type: mimeType }); })
    );
}
```

I read this article already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/function-expected

However, I'm still not understanding what MS say.
This must be something wrong in my code.
Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Which line cause error? Are you able to create codepen or fiddle? And the function `PassingBlobToServer` is defined somewhere?

Comment: This error is showed here:  MsgBox("Error", error, "error", "#upload-image-modal");

Comment: Can you show us this function `MsgBox`? I think pure Javascript not support this function.

Comment: It doesn't matter in the function MsgBox. Without the function, it's still error. Something wrong must be here: `return new File([buf], fileName, { type: mimeType })` in `srcToFile` function.

Comment: `File()` contructor is not supported in Egde https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Comment: oke thanks you, I'm thinking the way to change this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911927/instantiate-file-object-in-microsoft-edge) will help you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(As @Tan Duong's help.)

Problem is browser compatibility.

[File() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) is not supported by Edge or IE.

Workaround: we can use [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) constructor (supported) instead:

```
var blob = new Blob([blobContent], {type : 'image/jpeg'});
```

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43241922/9156186

Comment: this was a live saver, thanks